# How to connect to one SSH server via another

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have `A` and `B` SSH servers, I could connect to `B` from everywhere, but to `A` I can connect from `B` only. To achieve it usually I connect to `B` and then type `ssh username@A`.

How could I connect to `A` via `B` without typing two times ssh commands ?
And keep possibility to connect to `A` and to `B` at the same time, by my wish.

Comment: Do your Server A has public IP and Server B dont have public IP..

Comment: @abhishek-amralkar They both has public IP's only `A` was configured to allow incoming ssh connection only from `B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with NAT. You make DNAT in the PREROUTING chain on B. You may forward port 23 on B to port 22 on A.

This obviously requires that forwarding in enabled in general (in the kernel) and that this specific forwarding is allowed (in the firewall).

Comment: yep, this true, I could do that, thanks. I just thought it's possible to achieve with help SSH server itself

Comment: You can do port forwading with SSH, too. You can (with a root login) even do that from outside. But I think that is more complicated. Reconfiguring the firewall is simple.

Comment: but in that case `A` server will ask username and password ?

Comment: If you connect to the forwarded port then you are effectively talking to A thus A will ask for credentials. BTW: iptables port forwarding consumes less resources than SSH port forwarding.

Comment: but how, in that case, I could have keys for A server on my computer which could be used to log in ?

Comment: @user171271 I don't understand what the problem is. Do you ask me how to copy the secret SSH keys from B to the computer from which you want to connect?

Comment: I just don't see which one key I should have on local machine ? If i would like to connect to A via B then I should have key from A, but how ssh will know that `ssh user@B -p 2222` actually means  user@A which would be forwarder via B

Comment: @user171271 The SSH login keys don't care about it which machine they are logging into. This problem affects the host keys only. You may get warnings if you have two host keys for the same IP address in you `known_hosts` file. This problem can be solved by adding `-o HostKeyAlias=hostkeyalias__server_A` and `-o HostKeyAlias=hostkeyalias__server_B` to the ssh calls (and changing the IP addresses in the file to `hostkeyalias__server_A` and `hostkeyalias__server_B`).

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to this is to do

```
ssh A -L 2222:B:22
```

followed by (from your desktop, *not* from A)

```
ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

It's true that this requires you to perform two logins, **but only for the first access to B**.  After that, you reuse the existing tunnel to log into B as many times as you like, by just repeating the second command.

In addition, if you're fed up of typing your password again and again, I recommend you to look into `ssh-agent`; fiddly to set up, but a huge time-saver once it's done.